# headerView in 2 Line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want my headerView to be in 2 line
[image]

```
lastUpdatedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: Int(self.tableView.bounds.width), height: 44))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `numberOfLines`:

```swift
lastUpdatedLabel.numberOfLines = 2
```

more about it you can read in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines)

Comment: Cool but how can I modify which text is in the next line?

Comment: You can add a `\n` as a new line, so your text should be similar to this: `"this is the first line\nAnd this is second"`

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to make the label 2 lines, you should set `numberOfLines` 2

> The maximum number of lines to use for rendering text.
>
> The default value for this property is 1.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines)

```swift
lastUpdatedLabel.numberOflines = 2
```

---

- But if you want to set height related to it's content you should set `numberOfLines` to 0. Then it takes intrinsic content height from it's content (text).

[IntrinsicContentSize Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize)

```swift
lastUpdatedLabel.numberOflines = 0
```